How to record screen with two ways audio?
I am trying to record the screen for an online meeting with my voice and the other side's voice.
I cannot use any other software because of company restrictions.
When I record the screen I can record my voice but I cannot record the other part voice.
Not sure if this is because of company restrictions or just the audio setting on my computer.
I am using Windows 10 with Office 365

Most video conferencing software supports recording the meeting. You should be aware in many jurisdictions it’s illegal to record someone without their explicit consent. Which is the reason Microsoft Teams for instance notifies all participant that the meeting will be recorded and a transcript will be created if that also is enabled. You need to configure your recording software to record both the input and output audio streams

As @Ramhound states, settings are specific to the conferencing app, but usually record all parties. E.G., Zoom: https://support.zoom.com/hc/en/article?id=zm_kb&sysparm_article=KB0059856, Teams: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/record-a-meeting-in-microsoft-teams-34dfbe7f-b07d-4a27-b4c6-de62f1348c24, Meet: https://support.google.com/meet/answer/9308681?hl=en . Note that meeting initiator can forbid recording on some platforms, e.g., https://support.google.com/a/answer/7557052?hl=en

thank you. the question is if there is anything I can do to have the other party recorded (assuming there is consent)

@tuli - You would have to configure the meeting software to use a virtual audio source, which can be then recorded, by the recording software. This all requires third-party software which you indicated you cannot implement per company policy which is the reason I didn't mention it. Why can't you use the meeting software to record the meeting?

Your company should provide the expertise and support to do this, if they allow it. You need to go to your employer and present this question.
